# Puts Ruby / Rails text in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puts

I have an elementary problem. I'm sure you can tell by the question that I am somewhat new to ruby and rails.

I have a navigation that I am trying to apply the "active" class to so I can style the active page differently. I have @cur_page set like this with a before_filter:

```
def cur_page
    @cur_page = params['action']
end
```

I am trying to simply output the text "active", but its not working.

```
<li class="button <%= "active" if @cur_page == "contact" %>"><%= link_to "Contact", :public_contact %></li>
```

I've also tried:

```
<li class="button <%= puts "active" if @cur_page == "contact" %>"><%= link_to "Contact", :public_contact %></li>
```

I've checked the instance variable to make sure that it is set, and it is displaying "contact" like I expect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `:public_contact`? I would recommend you to use [current_page?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page?) helper instead of `@cur_page`.

```
<li class="button <%= "active" if current_page?(public_contact_path(@contact) %>"><%= link_to "Contact", public_contact_path(@contact) %></li>
```

Replace `public_contact_path(@contact)` to valid route helper.

Comment: Awesome! Somehow I knew there was a better way for me to go about it. I had no idea that method existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with double quotes.

use 'active' instead of "active" 
use 'contact' instead of "contact"

```
<li class="button <%= 'active' if @cur_page == 'contact' %>"><%= link_to "Contact", :public_contact %></li>
```

Comment: It actually ended up that I was setting the cur_page to :contact and forgot to remove those declarations. So the before filter was setting it to "contact", and then before the page rendered in controller, it was being set to :contact. After I removed those, it worked fine. Thanks for the response!